# Deleting an exactly matching line from file in shell Script

Tags: unix, sed

I am working on a script that among other things will delete a line from a file. The line to be deleted is stored in a variable, and constructed from a command line argument. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
repo=$1
devscript=/usr/local/bin/svn-post-commit-update-$repo-dev
livescript=/usr/local/bin/svn-post-commit-update-$repo-live
sudoer="www-data    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: $devscript, $livescript"
sed -i '//$sudoer/ d' /home/bdugan/t.txt
```

And I am getting the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `$'

I realize that at this point there is some simple syntax issue that I've messed up, but for the life of me I can't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that you must use double quotes so the variable gets expanded. Otherwise, `sed` sees the dollar sign literally.

Also key is that your pattern contains slashes. You must use alternate delimiters:

```
sed -i "\|$sudoer|d" /home/bdugan/t.txt
```

Choose a delimiter that is unlikely to appear in the string.

Comment: Start with a double quote and end with a single quote? Naaaah! And I belive escaping the pipe is not needed.

Comment: @Jens: The quote mismatch was a typo. You are right about the delimiters. I had thought the alternate address delimiter was a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2):

Since your line contains <kbd>/</kbd> chars, it will mess up the `/regex/` delimiters for sed. You might want to use awk and use string equality instead of a regex:

```
awk -v line="$sudoer" '$0 == line {next} {print}' ~/t.txt > ~/t.txt.new &&
mv ~/t.txt ~/t.txt.old &&
mv ~/t.txt.new ~/t.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sed -e "'s@${sudoer}@@'" -e '/^$/d' -i /home/bdugan/t.txt
```

this will use `@` as delimiter which is only possible for substition commands and afterwards delete empty lines.

EDIT: you shall not use `/` as a delimiter for filenames and path since it may break your `sed` regex

Update:

If you're using `GNU sed` you can reduce the command to

```
sed -e "'\@${sudoer}@d'" -i /home/bdugan/t.txt
```

Comment: be aware, that this command will delete every empty line in your file. If this is not an issue, it should work for you.

Comment: You could rewrite regexp as "@${sudoer}@d".

Comment: no you can't since `sed` doesn't allow alternative delimiter for any command except substitution commands (at least this is said by the documentation of `sed`, maybe there were changes lately). Would you mind testing it on your local machine and tell me if it's working ?

Comment: GNU `sed` allows alternate delimiters for address selectors so you can do `"\@${sudoers}@d"` (the first must be escaped). I would prefer `"\|$sudoers|d"` because it's less visually "heavy".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, can you post your solution as an answer? It was what eventually worked for me.

Comment: @denniswilliamson cold medicine makes my brain furry... Thanks!